# OTA development build distribution of iOS app

Tags: ios, wifi, info.plist, ota

I am trying to wirelessly distribute a dev build. I have been able to successfully accomplish this but with one problem. My app has requires WiFi so it has "UIRequiresPersistentWiFi" key set to true in Info.pList.

But when I install the app wirelessly, this requirement does not seem to apply. I am not sure what I am missing.

I verified that the Info.pList contains the key but it does not apply when I install the app. Please advise.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an option in the settings of the OS where the users selects the Ask to Join Networks. If the User selects this option he/she will be prompted to join networks otherwise it will just use whatever connection is available.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW1) I understand that with the key `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` the OS only tries to open a WiFi and keep the connection open as long as the app is running. (Without, the connection is closed after 30min).

A Wifi connection is therefore no requirement to install or launch the app. The app can be launched even if there is no WiFi connection at the moment.

Comment: I have no problems installing or launching the app. I just want it to prompt the hotspots list (like how Safari does when the) so that the user can connect to them via that prompt, instead of going to Settings. This prompt shows up when I am running using Xcode.

Comment: @user591410 Explicitly stating which behavior you expect and what in your opinion the error is should be in question!